# angular/material2 modules like Button, ProgressBar, Input not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I installed angular/material2 using `npm install --save @angular/material`. I am using @angular/cli.

After `angular/material` is installed, the material folder which is under the `node_modules/@angular` folder, does not contain folders like *`button`, `button-toggle`, `card`* etc...that means I can't use the widgets in my app.

To solve this problem I did:

```
npm install --save @angular2-material/core
npm install --save @angular2-material/button
```

After that, I am puzzled on how to load the modules and use them. [This](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/getting-started-using-angular-material-2-in-an-angular-2-angular-cli-application-bbeecdf6bfe2) tutorial is the nearest one to solve my problem, however my environment and the environment on the tutorial are a bit different such as not having `angular-cli-build.js` and `system-config.ts` files.

The folder structure inside the material folder only contains `@angular`, `bundles`, `prebuilt-themes`, `typings` folders.

The following is my code which I copied from [here](https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app):

`app.component.ts`:

```ts
import {Component, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MdSnackBar, MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} 
from '@angular/material';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
    lastDialogResult: string;
    foods: any[] = [
        {name: 'Pizza', rating: 'Excellent'},
        {name: 'Burritos', rating: 'Great'},
        {name: 'French fries', rating: 'Pretty good'},
    ];
    progress: number = 0;
    constructor(private _dialog: MdDialog, private _snackbar: MdSnackBar) {
        // Update the value for the progress-bar on an interval.
        setInterval(() => {
            this.progress = (this.progress + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 
            1) % 100;
        }, 200);
    }
    openDialog() {
        let dialogRef = this._dialog.open(DialogContent);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            this.lastDialogResult = result;
        })
   }
   showSnackbar() {
       this._snackbar.open('YUM SNACKS', 'CHEW');
   }
}
@Component({
    template: `
        <p>This is a dialog</p>
        <p>
           <label>
                This is a text box inside of a dialog.
                <input #dialogInput>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p> <button md-button 
        (click)="dialogRef.close(dialogInput.value)">CLOSE</button> </p>
    `,
})
export class DialogContent {
    constructor(@Optional() public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogContent>) { 
}
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```html
<md-sidenav-container [class.m2app-dark]="isDarkTheme">

  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
    Sidenav
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <button class="app-icon-button" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <i class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu">menu</i>
    </button>

    Angular Material2 Example App

    <span class="app-toolbar-filler"></span>
    <button md-button (click)="isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme">TOGGLE DARK THEME</button>
  </md-toolbar>

  <div class="app-content">

    <md-card>
      <button md-button>FLAT</button>
      <button md-raised-button md-tooltip="This is a tooltip!">RAISED</button>
      <button md-raised-button color="primary">PRIMARY RAISED</button>
      <button md-raised-button color="accent">ACCENT RAISED</button>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <md-checkbox>Unchecked</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox [checked]="true">Checked</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox [indeterminate]="true">Indeterminate</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox [disabled]="true">Disabled</md-checkbox>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <md-radio-button name="symbol">Alpha</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button name="symbol">Beta</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button name="symbol" disabled>Gamma</md-radio-button>
    </md-card>

    <md-card class="app-input-section">
      <md-input-container placeholder="First name"></md-input-container>

      <md-input-container #nickname placeholder="Nickname" maxlength="50">
        <md-hint align="end">
          {{nickname.characterCount}} / 50
        </md-hint>
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container>
        <md-placeholder>
          <i class="material-icons app-input-icon">android</i> Favorite phone
        </md-placeholder>
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container placeholder="Motorcycle model">
        <span md-prefix>
          <i class="material-icons app-input-icon">motorcycle</i>
          &nbsp;
        </span>
      </md-input-container>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <md-list class="app-list">
        <md-list-item *ngFor="let food of foods">
          <h3 md-line>{{food.name}}</h3>
          <p md-line class="demo-secondary-text">{{food.rating}}</p>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <md-spinner class="app-spinner"></md-spinner>
      <md-spinner color="accent" class="app-spinner"></md-spinner>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <label>
        Indeterminate progress-bar
        <md-progress-bar
            class="app-progress"
            mode="indeterminate"
            aria-label="Indeterminate progress-bar example"></md-progress-bar>
      </label>

      <label>
        Determinate progress bar - {{progress}}%
        <md-progress-bar
            class="app-progress"
            color="accent"
            mode="determinate"
            [value]="progress"
            aria-label="Determinate progress-bar example"></md-progress-bar>
      </label>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <md-tab-group>
        <md-tab label="Earth">
          <p>EARTH</p>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Fire">
          <p>FIRE</p>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tab-group>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <md-icon>build</md-icon>
    </md-card>

    <md-card>
      <button md-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
        MENU
      </button>
    </md-card>

    <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
      <button md-menu-item>Lemon</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Lime</button>
      <button md-menu-item>Banana</button>
    </md-menu>

    <md-card>
      <p>Last dialog result: {{lastDialogResult}}</p>
      <button md-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">DIALOG</button>
      <button md-raised-button (click)="showSnackbar()">SNACKBAR</button>
    </md-card>

  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>

<span class="app-action" [class.m2app-dark]="isDarkTheme">
  <button md-fab><md-icon>check circle</md-icon></button>
</span>
```

I expect to get a result [like here](https://material2-app.firebaseapp.com/):

[image: Expected result]

But I got this result as shown below:

[image: result]

Comment: Did you try [Official guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Comment: yes i tried to strictly follow the Official guide but i did not do the part that says "Appendix: Configuring SystemJS" since i do not have SystemJS on my project by default.

Comment: Follow the guide, remove `@angular2-material` part. Add the modules in your `app.module.ts` and you should be able to use in your component html . What error are you getting.

Comment: please look at my question above i said i did `npm install --save @angular/material`

Comment: please give us the error you get. You need to import import `{ MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';` in each module using an angular material component, not only in the `AppModule`

Comment: `@angular2-material` is an alpha version and is deprecated. Also the guide from medium references alpha version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this line of code on `styles.css`:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

rather than on `app.component.css` solved the problem. In addition, I have made some changes in the app.component.html like:

```
<md-input-container placeholder="First name"></md-input-container>
```

to:

```
<md-input-container> <input mdInput placeholder="First Name"></md-input-container>
```

I can see that things need to be updated on the [angular/material2](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) official guide.

Answer (score 2):

From their [Getting Started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) page...

### Step 3: Import the component modules

Import the NgModule for each component you want to use:

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

Alternatively, you can create a separate NgModule that imports all of the Angular Material components that you will use in your application. You can then include this module wherever you'd like to use the components.

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
  exports: [MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule],
})
export class MyOwnCustomMaterialModule { }
```

Whichever approach you use, be sure to import the Angular Material modules after Angular's BrowserModule, as the import order matters for NgModules.

Comment: i already did as you wrote, it did not work, did you ever mention .js files on angular-cli.json? i never did anything on my angular-cli.json file

Comment: When importing the modules, it's easy to remember to import from '@angular/material' but forget to update the @NgModule imports: [] array.  That was my problem when I encountered this.